# Editor or Entry texts are blurred after scaling in Mac/iOS

Tags: ios, .net, zooming, maui, scale

I have used entry control in my .net maui app , So have tried to zoom the entry control the text is blurred.[Download Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMynl.jpg)

Have tried FontAutoScalingEnabled property and handler also but it is not worked .

Handler code :
platformView.ContentScaleFactor = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.NFloat)zoomFactor;

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this is a known issue related to [[MAC/iOS] Contents are blurred with scaling](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9420), you can follow up there.

Setting the `FontAutoScalingEnabled` property on text-based control's to `false` is useful when you want to guarantee that text is displayed at **a specific size**. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?view=net-maui-7.0#disable-font-auto-scaling

Also, from the docs: [UIView.ContentScaleFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.contentscalefactor?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), the default value depends on the underlying hardware and the backing view type. The value is typically either 2.0 or 1.0.